# In DRAM, why does the precharge operation come after the activate operation and not vice-versa?

Tags: memory, sdram, dram

Precharging sets the bit line voltage is set to Vdd/2. To read from a dynamic memory cell, the bit line voltage must be near Vdd/2 for the sense amplifier to amplify the data value correctly. Since the bit line acts as a capacitor, its voltage will drop over time.

Why, then, do DRAM state machines mandate the commands to follow the ACTIVATE -> READ/WRITE -> PRECHARGE pattern? The time between a precharge and activate command could be very long (8x tREFI in DDR SDRAM) -- would the bit line voltage not drop far below Vdd/2 in this time?

To me, it would make sense to first precharge the bitline, then read the data from the memory array and into the sense amplifiers. I don't see how a precharge is necessary *after* a cell's data has already been read.

Why is the precharge command mandated *after* a read operation is completed?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I know what precharge is, I even explain it in my post. I am asking why the DRAM state machine requests a precharge at the end of a read cycle (and not at the beginning). The OP under that post asked the same question I did, but got no response.

Comment: My knowledge around DRAM internals is a bit too rusty to give you a confident answer, but I do have a few notes based on my understanding: It's the row line rather than the bit line that gets charged. There's very little DC leakage current from the row line, in part because the attached FETs' Vgs and Vds aren't changing, so there's no capacitive divider effect from the Cgd/Cgs and everything kinda sits in a steady state. Any charge leakage from the row line is part of the minimum refresh period calculation.

Comment: If you refreshed first, then read, there'd be a greater latency to the first byte read, since you'd have to wait for the precharge rather than it already being done _after_ your last read. Doing it afterwards also permits features like auto-precharge after tRAS. Speculating a little: if you precharged first, then left the row line at 0V or Vdd after a read, then the magnitude of leakage from the cells to the row line would be heavily reduced for cells at the same potential, but _increased_ for cells at the opposing potential, so that'd almost certainly force a shorter refresh period.

Comment: @Polynomial This the first time I've read about the row/address/word line getting precharged instead of the data/bit line. Wouldn't increasing the word line voltage increase the cell's Vgs, therefore increasing leakage through the transistor from the capacitor? Your second comment (I'd post it as an answer if I were you) makes sense if I assume you're talking about precharging the bit line, instead.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is the bitline not the wordline. I was misremembering.

Comment: I'm not an authority on this forum but I think what you've written here qualifies as an answer. I can't find any other explanations (or guesses) of why this is so, so for right now this educated guess is the best we've got.

Comment: I've formatted my comment as an answer. It's possible that someone will come by later and provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refreshed first, then read, there'd be a greater latency to the first byte read, since you'd have to wait for the precharge rather than it already being done after your last read. Doing it afterwards also permits features like auto-precharge after tRAS.

I'm not 100% sure, but to speculate a little: if you precharged first, then left the row line at 0V or Vdd after a read, then the magnitude of leakage from the cells to the bit line would be reduced for cells at the same potential, but *increased* for cells at the opposing potential, so that'd almost certainly force a shorter refresh period.